# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. React Native Android

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

i was getting this error during build time of android after two weeks of install stripe sdk, it was running perfectly before. it also running and building perfectly in IOS devices.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65MI6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTVvd.png)

To Reproduce
Install using this code

````
Run ```yarn android
Terminal get error at 76% , appear this error : Unchecked cast : >Task: app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses Failed ( picture below)

Versions:: 

React versio": "17.0.2",
React native version: "0.68.2",
Stripe version: 0.19.0
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 31
````

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that there are duplicate `bouncycastle` modules in your Android project, and you should exclude one of them.

1. Go to `/android` folder and run `./gradlew app:dependencies` to view the gradle dependency tree. Search `org.bouncycastle` and you should find two matches (e.g., one under `com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android` and the other one under your other dependency)
2. Open the `build.gradle` file in `/android/app` folder and add the gradle configuration if you wish you exclude the bouncycastle required by Stripe.

```
implementation ('com.stripe:stripe-android:20.14.0') {
    exclude group: "org.bouncycastle", module: "bcprov-jdk15to18"
}
```

Comment: I have added this code in build.grade under /android/app ... but the error still remain same

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding the following lines in `app/build.gradle` dependencies:

```js
implementation (project(':stripe_stripe-react-native')) {
      exclude group: "org.bouncycastle", module: "bcprov-jdk15to18"
}
```